# using mysqli to extract custom data

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I am using a function in php for all select queries so that i can dynamically retrieve data from my database ..... I just wanted to know that is my code secure and efficient or if their is a better way to do this, if so please point me to the right direction...thanks

```
class mysql {
    private $conn;      
    function __construct(){
                $this->conn= new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
                if( mysqli_connect_errno() )  
                {  
                     trigger_error('Error connecting to host. '.$this->connections[$connection_id]->error, E_USER_ERROR);  
                }
    }
function extracting_data($table, $fields,$condition,$order,$limit){
        $query="SELECT ".$fields."
                FROM ".$table."
                WHERE id =".$this->sql_quote($condition)."
                ORDER BY ".$order."
                LIMIT ".$limit." ";
        //echo $query;
        if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->execute();
            $row = array_pad(array(), $stmt->field_count, '');
            $params = array();
                foreach($row as $k=>$v) {
                  $params[] = &$row[$k];
                }
            call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_result'),$params);
            $result = array();
            while($stmt->fetch()) {
                foreach ($row as $b=>$elem) {
                    $vals[$b]=$row[$b];
                }
                $result[]=$vals;
            }
            $stmt->close();
            return $result;

        }

    }
    function sql_quote( $value )
    {
        if( get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
        {
            $value = stripslashes( $value );
        }
    //check if this function exists
        if( function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" ) )
        {
              $value = mysql_real_escape_string( $value );
        }
    //for PHP version < 4.3.0 use addslashes
        else
        {
              $value = addslashes( $value );
        }
        return $value;
    }

}
```

Now to call the function I am using ::>

```
    $connection=New mysql();
$extract=$connection->extracting_data("tablename","id,name,points","$_GET['id']","date desc","0,10");
```

The function returns a multi-dimensional array in $result and stores it in $extract ,depending on the data I want to extract..
Any improvements or other suggestions would be appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding the results and having to do loads of looping, you could simply use [`mysqli::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and  [`mysqli_result::fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).

```
if($stmt = $this->conn->query($query)) {
    $result = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);                
    $stmt->close();
    return $result;
}
```

You would be better off binding your input variables rather than building up an SQL string containing them, but that may not be feasible using your current approach.

**Edit**

Sorry, I was an idiot and didn't notice that fetch_all() is only in PHP >= 5.3. You can still do this though which is simpler:

```
if($stmt = $this->conn->query($query)) {
    $result = array();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }               
    $stmt->close();
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should watch where the parameters for your function come from.  If they come from an unreliable source, then it's very insecure.

   If someone passes something like `1 ; DROP TABLE tablename ; SELECT * FROM dual WHERE 1` in the `$condition` parameter, you'll get the *Little Bobby Tables* scenario.

   - Your query will look like the following:

     SELECT  id, name, points
      FROM    tablename
      WHERE   id
      ORDER BY
              DATE DESC
      LIMIT 0, 10

   The `id` here will be casted to `BOOLEAN`, and the query will select all `id`s except `0` and `NULL`.

   Is it really what you want?

   You probably want to change your `$condition` to `'id = $id'` or something like that.

   - Do you really need this level of abstraction: generating queries from uknown tables with unknown fields but with predefined `SELECT / FROM / ORDER BY / LIMIT` stucture?

Comment: Yes, I am planning to take care of the parameters apart from that, are their any redundant lines of code or some bad practices maybe....

Comment: will it not select only the 10 id's due to  limit 0,10 or should I remove the where clause if I don't need it in some of my queries

Comment: .Creating different functions for every extraction would increase the size of the class and the number of functions, so I thought why not create a single function to extract all kinds of data...